# Using a relay to spread a load over two circuits

Tags: power, relay

The challenge is pretty straightforward. I have a freeze dryer that requires a dedicated 20 A circuit. It wants 20 A because it's running two electric motors (and some resistance heat). The freeze drier has two components:

The main unit is, essentially, a glorified freezer with the ability to warm trays to allow water sublimation. This unit plugs into the 20 A receptacle.

The second unit is a vacuum pump. It plugs into the main unit and is toggled on or off by the main unit. (Energy use appears to be 700-1000 W).

Neither unit, standing alone, needs more than 15 A (or even 10). But, together, it's  more than 15 A.

I'm wondering if I can split the load between 15 A circuits. All I need is some way for that standard outlet on the back of that freeze dryer component to send a signal to let the power flow to the vacuum pump. What I'm envisioning is some type of extension cord with two plugs and one receptacle. The extra plug doesn't carry substantial current, but merely registers when it's energized to activate the flow of current between plug 1 and the receptacle end. When plug 2 is energized (that is, when the main unit is calling for the vacuum pump) that allows plug 1 to feed the receptacle end (and, by extension, the vacuum pump).

I've worked out a solution that should work, and it's pretty low cost. First, use a power-outage sensor for a smart home system and plug it into the back of the main freeze dryer unit. Then, take a smart outlet and plug it into a separate circuit to feed the vacuum pump.

When the power outage sensor is energized (the main unit is calling for vacuum) then an automation would turn on the smart plug feeding the vacuum pump. When the power outage sensor loses power (when the main unit doesn't want the vacuum pump on), then the smart outlet is "off."

I just wonder if I'm missing a more elegant or simpler solution to my problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible with just a relay and possibly a couple of supporting components, but I think you'll have to wire it yourself and you may not be comfortable with that and it may void your home insurance. If you're asking for a product that already does it, that's a shopping question which is not allowed because answers get out of date quickly. Your smart home hack solution might work with off-the-shelf parts.

Comment: a third solution is get the freeze-dryer a dedicated 20A circuit like it's designed for

Comment: Thanks for the validation @user253751  sounds like I’m barking up the right tree, but probably not worth the effort. 

And agreed that wiring the 20A circuit is the easy solution. I’ve done it that way before. But I’m not sure if I want this unit to stay where I have it (new house). So would like to avoid cluttering my full breaker box if possible. Thanks again!

Comment: The folks at diy.stackexchange.com will say that if your breaker box is too full, get it replaced with a bigger one. Way bigger. Because boxes are quite cheap, but replacing them isn't. Builders use the smallest boxes because they are penny-pinchers but you actually want to leave enough room for future upgrades.